# Font on Mac Catalina

Tags: macvim, font

I just now upgraded to Catalina on Mac (10.15) and immediately ran into an odd font behavior: when I open a file with MacVim (8.1.1722 (157)), the letters with tails (g, y, p...) have their tails cut off at the base of the text (see screen shot).  I can temporarily fix the problem by enlarging and then reducing the font, but that's annoying to have to do every time I open a file.  The font is Menlo:Regular:11.  I don't mind going to either 10 or 12, but I don't know how to make that a default.

So I have two questions: is this a Vim problem that is targeted for fixing?  If not, how do I change the default font?

[image]

Comment: Font options controlled with `'guifont'` (I think)—but this is an odd bug. Consider filing with MacVim maintainers

Comment: A bug was [filed](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/905) and, as Motik indicated, should be resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

After Upgrading to Mac OS Catalina, I had the same issue with the same MacVim version. Updating MacVim, currently to 8.1.2234, solved the issue.
I simply used "Check for Updates..." in the menu.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score -1):

I’m also running macOS Catalina and MavVim 8.1.1722.

Although I’m using a [patched font for Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)—Deja Vu Sans Mono for Powerline—and everything looks great, I launched MacVim in default mode—no vimrc or plugins: `mvim -u NONE`.

Saw the issue with the font baselines getting cut off.

Probably the best idea is to use a different font; here’s how to do that with any font you may have installed. Add a line to your `vimrc` file that looks something like this:

```
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline:h11
```

In my testing, disabling **Use CoreText Rendering** (**MacVim** menu > **Preferences** > **Advanced**) also resolved the font issue but that seems like a last resort option, as it decreases rendering performance.

Comment: Welcome to this site @alwillis! Your answer doesn't really answers OP's issue since it only shows how to change the font to a one they are not using instead of trying to figure out why their font has an issue.

Comment: @statox: I posted a revised answer.